# Is there a way to use your voice to open apps in Android?

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command

Is there a way to use your voice to open an app in Android?

I would like to say the exact phrase, "Run GMail" and it starts the gmail app.

Comment: Never tried but heard that [AutoVoice](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-create-custom-voice-commands-with-tasker-and-aut-1282209195) can do such things. It needs Tasker to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. At least for some app names it should work fine. You should start a voice search with the "Google App" and press the microphone button in it to speak and say "open application". I've tested trying to open a couple programs:

- open gmail
- open telegram
- abrir caixa (Portuguese for open and a bank app...)
- open just java

All of those worked and it is not limited to English. If you have a phone like a Samsung Galaxy, I think there is another app that lets you voice control, but I am not sure if it is worse/better than the Google App.

References: ["Ok Google" voice search & actions](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2940021?hl=en) and some testing by myself on Android 5

Comment: Can you make it respond to "Run Gmail"?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it worked. Are you having any problems?

Comment: Ok thanks. I wanted to know if it was only my phone out it worked on other Android devices